# Non-breaking space in cite style

Tags: spacing, citing

I am using the .bst file "authordate-3" to create my references, with a citation in the text in the format (author, year). I would like to make the space between author and year a non-breaking space but I don't know what I am looking for in the .bst file to change that.

I have tried the `\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,~}{,}` command in the preamble and added in a `~` in the right place, but I am now ending up with a double space instead.

MWE below, and appropriate .bst and bib file can be downloaded from [here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/2010/rachel_sheldon/test)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[space]{cite}

\renewcommand\citepunct{,~} 

\let \cite \citep

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis feugiat ipsum. Aenean rutrum malesuada ultricies. In eu ullamcorper ipsum, vitae facilisis diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean fringilla, elit vitae lacinia vulputate, lectus erat imperdiet sem, sed posuere metus ligula in diam. Nullam vehicula tempor massa fermentum pharetra. Vestibulum at urna in nulla porttitor congue in ut erat. Morbi eget ante ac mi mattis fermentum et a massa. Nullam diam ante, faucibus a elementum vitae, pharetra et purus. Nunc lacinia magna at tellus pretium, ac iaculis urna facilisis. Mauris in scelerisque tortor~\cite{sheldon14}, id tincidunt ante. Morbi interdum sed nisi ac tempor. Nunc dictum, lectus sit amet egestas condimentum, leo est ultricies sapien, quis cursus lorem massa vel tellus. Sed sodales dapibus nisi pellentesque elementum.

\bibliographystyle{authordate3-edit}
\footnotesize
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.